# How to use Firebase Storage image with Google Cloud Vision API?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, google-cloud-vision

I have a webapp where users are authenticated anonymously with Firebase Auth. I store images from users in Firebase Storage, which behind the scenes is backed by a Google Cloud Storage bucket. When I try to use the Google Cloud Vision API from client-side javascript to get the image properties I get a permission error.

```
image-annotator::User lacks permission.: Can not open file: gs://MYAPP.appspot.com/photos/IMG_12345.jpg
```

If I make the image public, everything works. But this is user data and can't be public. How can I solve this?

My code for calling the vision api:

```
gapi.client.init({
    'apiKey': MY_API_KEY,
    'discoveryDocs': ['https://vision.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest'],
    // clientId and scope are optional if auth is not required.
    'clientId': MY_APP_ID + '.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'scope': 'profile',
  }).then(function() {
    // 3. Initialize and make the API request.
    return gapi.client.vision.images.annotate({
      "requests":
      [
        {
          "features":
          [
            {
              "type": "LABEL_DETECTION"
            },
            {
              "type": "IMAGE_PROPERTIES"
            }
          ],
          "image":
          {
            "source":
            {
              "gcsImageUri": "gs://MY_APP.appspot.com/photos/" + "IMG_12345.jpg"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.result);
  }, function(reason) {
    console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
  });
```

My code for uploading images to storage:

```
var file = e.target.files[0];
var metadata = {
  contentType: file.type
};
console.log(file);

var uploadTask = photosStorageRef.child(file.name).put(file, metadata);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to do this on the server side via something like [Google Cloud Functions](http://cloud.google.com/functions) ([see my example here](https://github.com/mcdonamp/flaming-specs)).

Client side will require that your API key have sufficient permission to access the photos, which will basically make the private photos public (because once the API key has permission to read them, what's to stop a malicious client from doing so?).

Comment: Is there any way to have per-user authentication for the photos? When accessing through the firebase storage this is possible, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/, specifically "Firebase Storage integrates seamlessly with Firebase Authentication to identify users, and provides a declarative security language that lets you set access controls on individual files or groups of files, so you can make files as public or private as you want."

Comment: Also, thanks. I've requested access to the cloud functions alpha. I suppose now I wait?

Comment: In Firebase land, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security

Comment: @MikeMcDonald  Is it possible to use firebase to match images that I capture.For example, I have store few images in firebase storage. Now i want to find similar images using one image using cloud vision API